# Сочетание знаков препинания со сноской и прямой речью

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, сноски

Нужно ли ставить точку после сноски, если в предшествующем тексте (в закавыченной цитируемой прямой речи) есть восклицательный (вопросительный) знак или многоточие?

1. Голос его дрожал от волнения: «Спеши, чтобы ревностной заботой отстоять доверенный тебе самим отечеством пост!»**.
2. «Мои благородные товарищи! — воскликнул он. — <...> восславит нас перед потомством из века в век...»***.

С одной стороны, есть восклицательный знак, но, с другой стороны, формально он не в конце предложения, ведь после кавычек есть ещё знак сноски.

Comment: Числа/буквы с точкой используются при нумерации. Сноски имеют другой вид.

Comment: _shampar: Числа/буквы с точкой используются при нумерации. **Сноски имеют другой вид.**_ === Да, другой. Но сможете ли Вы воспроизвести его на этом сайте?

Comment: @slava1947 Это проблема сайта и Автора вопроса. Скрин или скан вставил бы.

Comment: @shampar  "Сноски имеют другой вид" == В самом деле? Это новость для меня. Благодарю за ценную информацию по сути вопроса.

Comment: К сожалению, не всегда есть возможность вставить скрин, а ответ на вопрос нужен срочно. Но приятно, что есть и те люди, которые способны отличить сноску от нумерованного списка даже при скудных инструментах этого сайта.

Comment: Да, с обозначением сносок есть проблема. Я попыталась ее обойти (надеюсь, Вы не против такого оформления Вашего вопроса). Приятно, что смогла помочь.

Comment: Вы пришли с нехитрым вопросом, прочитать который и понять о чём речь, оказалось труднее, чем ответить по теме. У Вас на этот час 44 посетителя. Мне их жалко.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Голос его дрожал от волнения: "Спеши, чтобы ревностной заботой отстоять доверенный тебе самим отечеством пост!»**
(В качестве знака сноски использованы звездочки.)

Розенталь ([§138. Последовательность знаков при сноске](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/55.htm)):
**2.** Вопросительный или восклицательный знак, многоточие и кавычки ставятся перед знаком сноски, чтобы показать, что сноска относится ко всему предложению.

Лопатин ([Сочетание знаков препинания и последовательность их расположения](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=482)):
При оформлении сносок соблюдается следующая последовательность знаков.
**4.** Кавычки ставятся перед знаком сноски...

Если предложение заканчивается кавычками (то есть после них точка отсутствует), то она [точка] не требуется и после сноски.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.